# ubuntu_22 : ROS2_humble :/usr/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently I started working in ROS2, while using some of pcl function I face below error.

For `#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>`
I am getting the fatal error

```
/usr/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:44:10: fatal error: pcl/conversions.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <pcl/conversions.h>
```

Platform : Ubuntu 22.04

`ros-humble-pcl-conversions`        `2.4.0-4jammy.20221207.034537 amd64`        Provides conversions from PCL data types and ROS message types

`libpcl-dev`                     `1.12.1+dfsg-3build1amd64`        Point Cloud Library - development files

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410802/ubuntu_22-:-ros2_humble-:/usr/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:fatal-error:-pcl/conversions.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [gnykumar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28335/gnykumar@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2022-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-25**:
`libpcl-dev` is a system library. Do you have a `find_package(PCL REQUIRED ...)` statement in your CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

one of the missing part from my try, but I added that also in CMakeList `find_package(PCL COMPONENT REQUIRED)`, AND missed this part : `include_directories(   include   ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )` and before `ament_package()` add this - `ament_export_include_directories(include)` Now it is working.

---

Originally posted by [gnykumar@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28335/gnykumar@gmail.com/) with karma: 26 on 2022-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-26**:
Your ros app having a dependency on pcl_conversions in CMakeLists.txt should have been enough for your build to succeed. However, this is the correct workaround if that doesn't work for some reason.